# Defining a region per-page that text must skip for?

Tags: wallpaper

I'm using the wallpaper package to use a png as a border in my document. In addition to the border there is a decorative separator in the image as you can see here:
[image: example]

I'd like to configure the document text so that it will properly skip that decorative separator, by defining the height of the separator for accuracy.

Comment: Shouldn’t such a break only appear where it makes sense in the content?! I find it quite strange to imply a big break at random places in the text ...

Answer (score 1):

The `cutwin` package can do such things

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cutwin}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\mycut}{%
        0.1\textwidth, 0.3\textwidth,
        0.2\textwidth, 0.4\textwidth,
        0.3\textwidth, 0.5\textwidth}

\begin{shapedcutout}{2}{3}{\mycut}%
\lipsum[1]
\end{shapedcutout}

\end{document}
```